# Angular ng-repeat in table, adding extra rows

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I'm repeating the contents of a array using ng-repeat with Angular. After that, but in the same table, I want to add some extra rows with info. But because it is in the ng-repeat I get an angular error on {{getCartTotal()}}, which is now called infinite times.

Is there a way to stop the ng-repeat, or a other way to add extra rows after a ng-repeat in the same element?

This is the code I have (in Jade). Only the first tr must been repeating.

```
table.shop_table.woocommerce-checkout-review-order-table
   tbody
       tr(ng-repeat='product in shoppingCart')
          th 
             {{product.name}}
             span.count  x {{product.quantity}}
             td
                span.amount &euro; {{product.price * product.quantity | number:2}}
       tr.cart-subtotal(ng-repeat-end)
         th Subtotaal
           td
             span.amount &euro; {{getCartTotal()}}}
       tr.shipping
         th Verzendkosten
           td
            span 
              i 
                | Tijdelijk gratis!
        tr.order-total
          th
            strong Totaal
               td
                strong
                   span.amount &euro; {{getCartTotal())}}
```

Comment: You have an extra '}' behind getCartTotal()

Comment: ng-repeat-end used with ng-repeat-start and will be repeated too. Try to delete ng-repeat-end

Comment: @AlexanderAnikeev thank you! a 'simple' repeat is enough here!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Duplicate from comment.

`ng-repeat-end` used with `ng-repeat-start` and will be repeated too. Try to delete `ng-repeat-end`

```
tr(ng-repeat='product in shoppingCart')
    th 
        {{product.name}}
        span.count  x {{product.quantity}}
        td
          span.amount &euro; {{product.price * product.quantity | number:2}}
tr.cart-subtotal
    th Subtotaal
        td
            span.amount &euro; {{getCartTotal()}}
```